# Including parent objects in "require"d files

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

### Overview

I connect to a database in `index.php`, then import my `classes.php` file using `require_once()`. However, when connecting to the database, the database connection is undefined.

### Code

`index.php`

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
require_once("inc/classes.php");

/* ..... */

if($_POST["form"]=="login"){

    //Retrieve values
    $e = $_POST["email"];
    $p = $_POST["password"];

    //Data validation
    if(!filter_var($e, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)||strlen($e)<3) $errors->addError("email", "Please enter a valid email address.");
    if(strlen($p)<1) $errors->addError("password", "Please enter a valid password");
    $errors->killErrors();

    //Log user in
    $user = new User($e);
    if(!$user->login($p)) $errors->addError("form", "Incorrect username or password.");
    $errors->killErrors();

    exit("success");
}
```

`inc/classes.php`

```
class User
{
    public $id, $email, $data;

    public function __construct($e = null){

        if(isLoggedIn()){
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=? LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION["userid"]));
            $this->data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } else $this->email = $e;

    }

    public function login($p){
        //Perform database query for user
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(array($this->email));
        if($stmt->rowCount()<1) return false;

        //Check password is correct
        $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!password_verify($p, $data["password"])) return false;

        if(!$this->email) exit("User can only be logged in with an email address, not by User ID");

        $this->id = $data["id"];
        return $this->validate($this->id) ? true : false;
    }

}
```

### Output

> **Notice:** Undefined variable: dbh in **/var/www/html/foo/public_html/bar/inc/classes.php** on line **80**
>
> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function prepare() on null in **/var/www/html/foo/public_html/bar/inc/classes.php** on line **80**

Line 80 is:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=? LIMIT 1");
```

### Question

How can I include the database connection in `index.php` and have the `classes.php` file accept that PDO object?

Comment: You have to make it `global $dbh;` inside the function. It is a [scope issue](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: @JayBlanchard - directly inside the class or the individual function(s)? I've heard using `global` is not advised - is this still the case inside classes?

Comment: Done carefully it is OK, many use it too haphazardly and have a tendency to want to globalize all of their variables. I personally do it within the function to eliminate ambiguity.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks - tested and working. If you post that as an answer I'll accept, cheers

Comment: You can also pass  `$dbh` in function parameter  as `login($p,$dbh)` get it using`function login($p,$dbh)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make your connection global:

```
global $dbh;
```

Because of [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Done carefully it is OK to use global variables. Many use it too haphazardly and have a tendency to want to globalize all of their variables. I personally do it within the function inside the class to eliminate ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php - as @JayBlanchard writes, you need to reference the connection handle as a global variable.

However, it's much cleaner to pass dependencies into your object. For instance, when instantiating your User, you can pass in the connection.

```
$user = new User($dbh, $e);
```

You can then set a private variable for the connection handle. This way, you can change the name of the variable in index.php, or change the way it's instantiated without your User class blowing up due to a change in a different file.